# Relationship between $ \operatorname{Hom} (A, -)$ and $ \operatorname{Hom}(-, B)$ functors?

Tags: category-theory, definition

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor#Formal_definition) states that:

> The pair of functors $ \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(A, –)$ and $ \Hom(–, B)$ are related in a natural manner.

Than there is a commuting diagram, which I can't understand. Let's take one of its paths:
$ \Hom(A, B) \xrightarrow{\Hom(A, f: B \rightarrow B')}  \Hom(A, B') \xrightarrow{\Hom(h: A \rightarrow A', B')}  \Hom(A', B')$

So, $\Hom(A, B) \xrightarrow{\Hom(A, f: B \rightarrow B')} \Hom(A, B')$ maps $\{ A \rightarrow B \}$ arrows to the $\{ A \rightarrow B' \}$ arrows by a known way. Here things getting unclear to me: according to the path above, next morphism is $\Hom(h: A \rightarrow A', B')$. The problem is that it does not work with arrows of type $\{ A \rightarrow B' \}$, it instead expects arrows of type $\{ A \leftarrow B' \}$.

Hence, I got stuck.

I assume that this is some kind of common "abuse of notation".

I would like to know how to read abovementioned diagram and define proper natural transformation (or natural isomorphism?) between the pair of functors $\Hom(A, –)$ and $\Hom(–, B)$?

Comment: If $\mathcal C$ denotes the category then $\mathsf{Hom}(A,-):\mathcal C\to\mathbf{Set}$ but $\mathsf{Hom}(-,B):\mathcal C^{\text{op}}\to\mathbf{Set}$. So they have different domains so that there is no natural transformation.

Comment: @drhab, do you claim that wiki is mistaken and $Hom(A, -)$, $Hom(-, B)$ do not relate in a natural way?

Comment: No I am not saying that. I am only saying that a natural transformation between both functors  (that you would like to define) does not exist. For that you need functors $F,G:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C'$ having the same domain and codomain. So "related in a natural manner" is not the same as "existence of natural transformation".

Comment: @drhab, why then wiki states that both relate in a natural way, linking natural transformation?

Comment: The diagram shown looks quite natural. It visualizes a natural transformation $\mathsf{Hom}(A,-)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A',-)$ and also a natural transformation $\mathsf{Hom}(-,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(-,B')$. For the first we have components $\mathsf{Hom}(h,B):\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A',B)$ and for the second components $\mathsf{Hom}(A,f):\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A,B')$. In both cases the transformation is completely determined by an arrow ($h$ in first and $f$ in second case) corresponding with Yoneda.

Comment: There is a typo in the question: if $h \colon A \to A'$ then $\mathcal C(h,B') \colon \mathcal C(A',B) \to \mathcal C(A,B)$, the direction is reversed, that's because that's a contravariant functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: the commutativity of the diagram tell us *two things at the same time* and both things involve natural transformations:

- If $\tau_B:=\mathsf{Hom}(h,B):\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A',B)$ for every object $B$ then $\tau$ is a natural transformation $\mathsf{Hom}(A,-)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A',-)$.
- If $\rho_A:=\mathsf{Hom}(A,f):\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(A,B')$ for every object $A$ then $\rho$ is a natural transformation $\mathsf{Hom}(-,B)\to\mathsf{Hom}(-,B')$.

Let $\mathcal C$ denotes the category that is involved.

Then $h$ denotes an arrow in homset $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}(A,A')=\mathcal C(A',A)$ and $\tau_B=\mathsf{Hom}(h,B)$ is prescribed by: $$u\mapsto u\circ h$$

Further $f$ denotes an arrow in homset $\mathcal C(B,B')$ and $\rho_B=\mathsf{Hom}(A,f)$ is prescribed by: $$u\mapsto f\circ u$$

Comment: I can't follow. AFAIU, $Hom(h, B)$ is $Hom(B, A) \rightarrow Hom(B, A')$, but your statement is on the contrary. And what does it mean, that $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}(A,A')=\mathcal C(A',A)$? Do you mean that both sets are isomorphic?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov, you are mistaken,  $Hom(h,B) \colon Hom(A,B) \to Hom(A',B)$. The equation $\mathcal C^\text{op}(A,A') = \mathcal C(A,A')$ is the definition of the hom-set of arrows from $A$ to $A'$ into the _opposite category_ $\mathcal C^\text{op}$: the category obtained by $\mathcal C$ reversing the direction of the arrows.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, what is $Hom(B, h)$ then?

Comment: Let $h:A'\to A$. Then $\mathsf{Hom}(h,B)$ is a function that has $\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)$ as domain. Element $u\in\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)$ is sent to $u\circ h\in\mathsf{Hom}(A',B)$. Are you familiar with opposite category?

Comment: A function of type $Hom(B,A') \to Hom(B,A)$, assuming $h \colon A \to A'$.

Comment: Oh, finally I got it, thanks! I didn't take $Hom(-, B)$ consrtuction correclty...

Comment: @GiorgioMossa you mean: "assuming $h:A'\to A$...."

Comment: @drhabdrh, yep sorry for the typo.